# How to stop redirect if user is already on correct page (Using Case Switch)

Tags: users, redirect

I am using WordPress Multisite with Paid Membership Pro for two types of member users (Corporate companies, individuals). I have subsites for the corporate users (ex. corporate.mysite.com) that has member access to content on mysite.com. I have setup different 'Dashboards' for individual tiers and corporate users. For instance a 'rookie' user is redirected to mysite.com/rookie-dashboard/ and a corporate user is redirected to corporate.mysite.com/dashboard/ after logged in. Each member is setup as a subscriber and is assigned a user level ID based on which package they purchased (via PaidMembershipPro)

That said, I'm trying to setup a function switch redirect if a user tries to access the wrong dashboard. Here is what I have setup so far:

```
 function dashboard_redirect()
{
    global $current_user, $post;


        switch ($current_user->membership_level->id) {
        case "2":
        // Rookie Member level
        wp_redirect('/rookie-dashboard/');
        break;
        case "3":
        // Player Member level
        wp_redirect('/player-dashboard/');
        break;
        case "4":
        // All-Star Member level
        wp_redirect('/allstar-dashboard/');
        break;
        case "5":
        // Coach Member level
        wp_redirect('/coach-dashboard/');
        break;
        case "6":
        // Owner Member level
        if (! is_page(197) ) { 
            return false; 
        } else {
     wp_redirect('/dashboard/'); 
}
        break;
        case "7":
                if (! is_page('/dashboard/') ) { 
            return false; 
        } else {
        // Corporate
        wp_redirect('http://corporate.mysite.com/dashboard/');
                }
        }   

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect');
```

The issue that I am running into is nulling the process when the right user is on their dashboard page. I get infinite loops if I just have a switch casse with the redirects so I tried adding a if/then to the switch but can't seem to get it to work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `template_redirect` fires on every public page load. That means that after you redirect a user to a specific page, `template_redirect` fires again, even if they're already on the correct page. You just need to add a check to see if the current page they are on is same as where they should be.

```
function dashboard_redirect() {
  global $current_user, $post;

  //* Escape early if not on a 'dashboard' page
  $current = trailingslashit( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] );
  if( false === stripos( $current, 'dashboard' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  switch ( $current_user->membership_level->id ) {
    case "2":
      // Rookie Member level
      $redirect = '/rookie-dashboard/';
      break;
    case "3":
      // Player Member level
      $redirect = '/player-dashboard/';
      break;
    //* Etc.
  }

  //* Redirect if we're not already on the right page
  $current = trailingslashit( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] );
  if( $current !== $redirect ) {
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
  }
}

//* Conditionally add action when user tries to access a 'dashboard' page
$current = trailingslashit( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] );
if( false !== stripos( $current, 'dashboard' ) ) {
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect' );
}
```

---

Added example code on how you can conditionally add the hook OR how to escape early from the callback if we're not on a dashboard page. Use one or the other. I'd probably use the escape method, but only because it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! How can I make it so that the template redirect is only triggered on the Dashboard Pages? For instance I have the 5 member level dashboard pages on the main site and the corporate dashboard on the subsite. Right now, the way it's setup I am unable to go to any other page on the site.